# Node Dev Tools completely black while decrypting files

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, encryption, electron

I have a program that decrypts a bunch of files using C# with a html/js/css UI using electron-edge.

At some point during decryption, the dev tools window goes completely black. The UI of my program is still responsive, but the dev tools are gone. The <kbd>f5</kbd> shortcut doesn't work either.

It crashes right at the start of the decryption of the 5th file. Is there any way that the thing crashed without any notice or error message while doing any of this (maybe due to memory constraints or smth):

```
    byte[] passwordBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Password);
    byte[] salt = new byte[32];

    FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(InputFile, FileMode.Open);
    fsCrypt.Read(salt, 0, salt.Length);

    RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged();

    AES.KeySize = 256;
    AES.BlockSize = 128;

    var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, salt, Constants.Encryption.HashIterations);
    AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
    AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);
    AES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    AES.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;

    CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt, AES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);

    FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(OutputFile, FileMode.Create);


    int read;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1048576];

    try
    {
        long totalBytes = new FileInfo(InputFile).Length;
        long readBytes = 0;

        int progress = 0;
        int progress_last = 0;

        while ((read = cs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            if ((bool) await cm.isCancelled(null))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Extraction was cancelled ...");
                await Progress.reset(new { type = CURRENT });
                (new FileInfo(LogFile)).Directory.Create();
                File.AppendAllText(LogFile, "Extraction was cancelled ...");
                break;
            }
            readBytes += read;
            fsOut.Write(buffer, 0, read);

            progress = getProgress(readBytes, totalBytes);



            if ((progress - progress_last) > PROGRESS_STEPSIZE || progress == 100)
            {
                await Progress.setProgress(new { type = CURRENT, value = progress });
                progress_last = progress;
            }

            // PROGRAM DOESN'T REACH THIS POINT
            Console.WriteLine("Decrypting: " + progress + " %");

        }
    }
    catch (System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException ex_CryptographicException)
    {
    // ... and so on an so forth. All errors are handled accordingly and will at minimum Console.Writeline() it. No error shows up. ...
```

Any ideas on where this could come from? If I just decrypt the files without downloading them first (through the program), everything works fine ...

Another note: The first 4 files were each 30-40 mb, that 5th one is 90mb.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Is the above code all inside a larger loop e.g. for each file?

Comment: I really don't see how you call the C# code when you're using electron. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @LukePark Yes it is. It loops through all the files inside a fiber

Comment: @ArtjomB. That's possible with electron-edge

Comment: The problem is likely then that you don't dispose of any of the resources you create in each iteration of the while loop.  The `RijndaelManaged`, `FileStream` etc. all need to be disposed of.  Learn how to use the `using` statement in C#.

Comment: @LukePark I actually did close all the resources, but I noticed something else while testing: The 5th file just happens to be a special one. 1-4 were normal files, the 5th one has to be unblocked before downloading (nothing illegal going on here dw). In the process of unblocking, the file is being written twice (one fails because it's blocked, the second one works). However, the first node filewritestream might not be closed so it says "can't open file to decrypt" (if I specifically test for that error because I can't see any devtoolsoutput). I'll do some testing and will answer this question.

Comment: Update: Seems like that was the problem. Will create a full answer once I have time for that. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You don't close any resources in the code above.  Please make sure your code in the question reflects what you are actually doing...

Comment: @LukePark Ye, sorry. I do close them before returning. Didn't include that part because I didn't think it was necessary. Will do that next time though. I now restructured that whole decryption process anyway.

Comment: If you intend to answer your own question you need to ensure that the code in your question is consistent with what you are actually doing.  Include the part where you dispose of the resources.  If the the code above is in a while loop then I don't see how you are disposing of them.

Comment: @LukePark It's a lot of code in a bunch of different files, but I will update my question accordingly once I figured it out. I got it to decrypt all files but the last so far, let's see why that last one doesn't make it :/